# How to change the array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this

```
array =  [{name: 'John'},{age: 20},[{degree: "any"}, {college: 'any'}]]
```

I want to change this array into something like this..

```
array =  [{name: 'John'},{age: 20},{degree: "any"}, {college: 'any'}]
```

variable array is returned from different recursive functions, degree and college is returned from single function as an array of object.

Comment: `array.flat()` Simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
array =  [{name: 'John'},{age: 20},[{degree: "any"}, {college: 'any'}]]

console.log(array.flat())
```

flat() solves your problem.